# Joblib parallelization of function with multiple keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, joblib

I have a big and complicated function which can be reduced to this prototype function for demonstration purpose :

```
def test(a, b, op="", ex=[]):
    print(op)
    ex = len(ex)
    if op=='add':
        return a+b+ex
    elif op=='mult':
        return (a*b)+ex
    elif op=='div':
        return (a%b)+ex
    else:
        return -1
```

I've been trying to run two jobs on this function parallelly with possibly different keyword arguments associated with them. I can run with arguments like this had there been no keyword args :

```
o1, o2 = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(test)(*args)
    for args in (
        [1, 2],
        [101, 202]
    ))
```

For passing keyword args, I thought of this :

```
o1, o2 = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(test)(*args, **kwargs)
    for args, kwargs in (
        [1, 2, op='div'],
        [101, 202, op='sum', ex=[1,2,9]]
    ))
```

But obviously it should give some syntax error at `op='div'` part. I also tried this :

```
o1, o2 = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(test)(*args, **kwargs)
    for *args, kwargs in (
        [1, 2, {op: 'div'}],
        [101, 202, {op:'sum', ex:[1,2,9]}]
    ))
```

But then this would show this error :

> NameError: name 'op' is not defined

I have also tried this :

```
o1, o2 = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(test)(*args, **kwargs)
    for args, kwargs in (
        [(1, 2), {op: 'div'}],
        [(101, 202), {op:'sum', ex:[1,2,9]}]
    ))
```

Same error :

> NameError: name 'op' is not defined

So I tried this :

```
o1, o2 = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(test)(*args, **kwargs)
    for args,kwargs in (
        [1, 2, {'op': 'div'}],
        [101, 202, {'op':'sum', 'ex':[1,2,9]}]
    ))
```

Now I get this :

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

How do I pass keyword arguments to the function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in defining your dictionaries

```
o1, o2 = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(test)(*args, **kwargs)
for *args, kwargs in (
    [1, 2, {'op': 'div'}],
    [101, 202, {'op':'sum', 'ex':[1,2,9]}]
))
```

This should also work (notice args are in list not unpacked with star):

```
o1, o2 = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(test)(*args, **kwargs)
for args, kwargs in (
    [(1, 2), {'op': 'div'}],
    [(101, 202), {'op':'sum', 'ex':[1,2,9]}]
))
```